# URL por ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Queria passar uma URL pela ViewBag, mas não consegui. queria fazer asim:

```
ViewBag.Quantidade = "Você Não tem quantidades suficientes, para continuar você deve comprar um Pacote";
```

ai no caso o texto "comprar um pacote" fosse um link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com [***Html.Raw***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx), que na tradução diz que [a seqüência de caracteres para interpretar como marcação HTML em vez de HTML codificado](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896(v=vs.111).aspx). (*tradução:* `HtmlHelper.Raw Method` (`String`)).

***Controller:***

```
ViewBag.Quantidade = 
    string
     .Format("Você Não tem quantidades suficientes, para continuar você deve {0}",
             "<a href=\"/home/usuario\">comprar um Pacote</a>");
```

---

***View:***

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Quantidade)
```

Comment: Jóia! funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado @Virgilio